# Cable for Kinect - XBox 360 and cable for Kinect - Xbox One

Tags: kinect

I dont have any of the above and hence wanted to ask if anyone knows if the cable running from Kinect v1 to Xbox 360 and the cable running from Kinect v2 to Xbox One is identical?

I want to use Kinect V2 just for PC ( without Xbox ) and hence was looking for cheap solutions ( avoiding to buy the expensive usb adaptor from microsoft )

Comment: FYI, you can also use the edit button instead of deleting & re-creating questions. This can be a better strategy because StackExchange's automated low-quality content filters include deleted questions, so having a lot of them can make your account look like a spammer or vandal, when you're actually striving for good quality.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a general hardware question which has nothing directly to do with game development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the cables and their connectors are not the same.

[image: Photos of the connector cables & adapters for the two Kinect versions]

[image: Diagram of the USB cable on the original Kinect]

[image: Kinect for Xbox 360 with power adapter]

The original Kinect for Xbox 360 uses a proprietary connector that looks similar to USB-A, but with traces on both sides and a beveled corner. It uses more power than standard USB. Later 360 models included a dedicated port for this connector so it could be hooked up directly. To use it with a PC or the earlier Xbox 360 models, you need an additional adapter that forks it off into a regular USB-A cable and an AC transformer plug.

[image: Diagram of the USB & power adapter cable for the Kinect for Xbox One]

The Kinect for Xbox One uses an L-shaped proprietary connector with two internal slots. Connecting it to the PC requires using a more elaborate adapter with two connection boxes: one that converts it into USB-A and a DC power input, and a separate AC transformer block.

Note that even with this adapter, not every USB 3 port will support the high bandwidth required by the device.

[image: Kinect for Windows]

There's also a Kinect for Windows model, similar to the Kinect for Xbox One but outputting to USB directly (still with an extra cable for power, included in the package). So this might be an option for you, though anecdotally I've experienced stability issues with this model that I did not see with the Kinect for Xbox One + adapter. The problems only showed up after repeated sensor connections & disconnections in a single session, so they might not manifest for every application.

Comment: So, is it possible to use the second pic setup ( daisy chained adapter cable ) with Kinect for Xbox One instead of Kinect for Xbox360? Looking at this video, it is no different than the second pic you posted  - .https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l0rWWT24TNE

Comment: Am jst curious, what does this overtly expensive microsoft adatpor ( your third pic ) actually has, because the youtube video makes the task pretty simple.

Comment: Now that I'm home I've edited the post to include photos of my Kinect connectors, so you can see very clearly the adapter for one won't fit the other. (I'd also misremembered the Xbox 360's Kinect cable being standard USB-A, when it's actually a unique connector that's just similar in size & shape)

Comment: The "overly expensive adapter" is something I've actually had in my hands. It is, as far as I could tell, an "overly large and overly expensive" way of supplying power and adapting the plugs. (It weighed like ten pounds).

Comment: @Draco18s its funny, because there are cheap adapters for less than 4 euros for xbox360, but not for xbox one.. It looks like from the answer and the you tube video, that the only difference between the two is the form factor. Hence, cant understand, why arent cheap adatpers available for xbox one !

Comment: @DMGregory . could you please check one last thing - if its possible to insert a usb Type A in the upper slot of the xbox one adapter? If yes, I would assume that the lower slot is the 12V DC and I could easily make an adapter without opening the Kinect as suggested in the you tube video. I guess, the answer is no, coz otherwise, other people would have already done it.. But still would be great to confirm.

Comment: It's too narrow for a standard type-A connector with its grounded casing to fit inside, and there are metal traces on both sides of the slot, rather than on just one side as we'd expect with type-A.

Comment: @infoclogged It might be doing other things, I don't know. I never took it apart, and honestly, didn't even end up needing it at all (because I used a 360 Kinect).

Comment: At this point we're well outside our subject area of game development and into electronics hacking. If you want to try to adapt the cable yourself that's not something we can help you with on this site.